# how to search program in /usr/sbin via DASH

Tags: installation, unity-dash, installed-programs

I'm using TEXT Editor. I've executable for that....I put it in `/usr/sbin` and now i can turn it ON via commandLine. 
Now how will that application will be installed. I mean how can i directly search that application from DASH and use it, instead of using commandLine everytime.

Comment: This application wasn't there in Software Center....

Comment: I am the author of the rtf editor you refer to. Why did you not just contact me through support?, or at least post on the genscriber apps support forum.
The editor was intended to be mobile.
If you wanted an installed version that could be have been supplied quite easily. I have never been able to understand why people download free apps and then give no feedback to the author. Les Hardy genscriber.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to make a .desktop file for it and it needs to contain `Terminal=true` so that running it will also open your preferred terminal. You place the desktop file in either `/usr/share/applications/appname.desktop` if you want it for all users in the system, or in `$HOME/.local/share/applications/appname.desktop` if you only want it for yourself.

The desktop entry specification can be found here: http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/

And remember to run `update-desktop-database` afterwards so you don't have to log out and back in for it to work.

Comment: Finally you edited your answer and did same what I suggested.. :) That was good..

Comment: The link you gave me, has lots of INFO.....
Can you actually tell me, how to make sample desktop file.
My application name is "Editor".

Answer (score 2):

You should add your application as a **New Item** in [**Main Menu** (alacarte) [image: Install alacarte]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/alacarte/) (it's not installed by default, but can be found in **Ubuntu Software Center**).

To open **Main Menu**, search in **Dash** for `alacarte`:

[image: alacarte]

[image: main menu]

[image: create launcher]

Comment: But alacarte isn't installed by default. I didn't know it had been separated into its own package! Great tip :)

Comment: @Jo-ErlendSchinstad I forgot that is not installed by default. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you, but i prefer it by making .desktop file. That was better wa .

Comment: @user182904 And what do you think that it does?!? It automatically create a .desktop file in `/usr/share/applications/` :) See the link that I gave you in the answer.

Comment: yes, i understand, ultimately it has do that....but for that little purpose installing a application....!!!

Comment: @user182904 As I can see from your answer, yes, is better (have only 1,2 MB on disk) because you may wrong in some cases when you manually edit a .desktop file.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for Answers. 
For normal purpose: One needs to make `application.desktop` file.

- If you want it for all users in the system, place it in `/usr/share/applications`.
- If you only want it for yourself in `$HOME/.local/share/applications/`

Information Required(for more info : [linkToMoreInfo](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/))

1. Name=Application Name
2. Exec=Application Path
3. Terminal=true/false   //if you want to open terminal with your application or not.
4. Icon=Address of the ICON for application.

Eg:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=RTF EDITOR
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=Edit RTF files
Keywords=Plaintext;Write;
Exec=rtfed
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
```

And now do this, so that it is available in DASH search: `sudo update-desktop-database`.
**thanks @Jo.**

Comment: Sorry, but I have to correct you. The minimal information required is:  `Type=Application/Link/etc` and one of these two: `Exec=/path/to/app` or `URL=web_address`. See http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ :D

Comment: I concur....that wasn't minimal INFO..:D :D

Comment: Oh, and you should run the update-desktop-database command afterwards. :)

Comment: @Jo-ErlendSchinstad thanks for that....that was the missing part in the puzzle....